# Cannot access SQLite on Android L with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, sqlite, intellij-idea, android-sqlite

I get this error in the IntelliJ event log, when I try to access SQLite on Android L with IntelliJ IDEA:

`Data Source Synchronization Error: Cannot synchronize 'Android SQLite': error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is fixed in IntelliJ 15 EAP.